# Gradle project refresh failed. Android Studio

Tags: android

I get this error when trying to run my App on Android Studio. Does anyone know what the reason could be? Thanks.

```
Gradle 'MyApp' refresh failed.

Error:Cannot locate factory for objects of type DefaultGradleConnector, as ConnectorServiceRegistry has been closed.
```

Comment: I am assuming you tired cleaning the project and restarting AS?

Comment: Yes. That what I have done over and over.

Comment: @RonnyKibet I am facing same issue, can you please post How do you fixed it?

Comment: This sounds of a implicit Gradle issue.So you could try running `gradle build` from the command line.

Comment: Restart Android studio will fix it.

Answer (score 100):

Restarting Android Studio usually fixes this error for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @P.T.: Why is this not an answer to the question? Question: "I get this error". Answer: "Restarting Androi Studio fixes this error".

Comment: Read the comments.  The poster already tried that.  Plus, this doesn't really answer the question (which is why this is happening, not how to ignore this.)

Comment: figured. this is more like an error caused by SDK update. restart Android studio works for me.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, why some people said it is not good?

Answer (score 55):

You can restart android studio like this:

Click  File ----> Invalidate Caches /Restart

[image]

It works for me!

Comment: Yes, restarting of AS can't help in this problem. Only Invalidate Caches /Restart.

Comment: This temporary solves the error, but it can arise once again as soon as after one app lunch

Answer (score 8):

Open Your **Android Studio Terminal** 

Type command `> gradlew clear` press **Enter** 
and select option in

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Then press `Restart` button. 
Now clear your `app.gradle`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Did you update Android Studio to it's latest version?

This is a bug that was present in RC1 but should be fixed in the latest version, according to:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80591

Comment: I have Android Studio 1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

**Working Solution :**

File ->Invalidate Cache and Restart

Answer (score 1):

If nothing worked, simple solution worked for me, you need to change maven version:

from

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
```

Android Maven Versions: [Link](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin#note-on-releases)

Android Maven Incompatible with gradle 2.14 Fix: [Link](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/33)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Terminal and type clearw Gradle -> press Enter -> after finish this step goto file menu choose Invalidate Caches /Restart-> press Yes