# Gradle Project Sync Faild in android studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, gradle

When I tried to create a new project in android studio 2.3.1 I get this error

Error:Cannot locate factory for objects of type DefaultGradleConnector, as ConnectorServiceRegistry has been closed.

I tried to restart android studio but the problem not solved.

This kind of question may be asked earlier but I don't get the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle project refresh failed. Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724883/gradle-project-refresh-failed-android-studio)

Comment: Try this, Build-> Clean Project or File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart